# Capacitor "blocking DC" in a low pass filter

Tags: capacitor, dc, low-pass

If we imagine a basic lowpass filter, the AC components from the non perfect DC from VIN passes the capacitor and down to ground, meanwhile "pure" DC flows to VIN.

If we take a basic closed DC circuit with a battery capacitor, once the capacitor reaches the voltage level of the battery, no current will flow, and therefore "DC is blocked".

So I assume that the capacitor in a lowpass filter act the same. Once its charged and equals the voltage of VIN, no DC will pass.

But what about the AC components/ripple, they pass, do they affect that capacitors charge/discharge.
How does the capacitor ever charge/discharge in a lowpass filter like this? Where VIN is DC with AC components.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [The capacitor in a low pass filter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/700950/the-capacitor-in-a-low-pass-filter). If you have additional information related to your original question, use the "edit" button to add the information there. It was put "on hold" in order to allow you to improve it before people try to answer it. Do not create a duplicate question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to understand that AC currents flow through a capacitor.

And current is moving charges.

Any time there is a current through a capacitor, the current either charges the capacitor by adding charge, or discharges it by removing charge, and by definition, the voltage of a capacitor depends on the charge stored in it, and capacitance is the relation how much voltage changes when charge changes.

Comment: Yeah found my answer online, the ripple current is not the same as AC though, we do not invert and get a negative current like a sine wave, therefore we do not change direction in our charge/discharge. Other than that you are right, charge with rising ripple current and discharge with falling ripple is how it gets flattened into proper DC

Comment: @Larius They are the same thing. I think what you mean is that the capacitor only discharges and charges a bit when you talk about ripple, and AC when it charges and discharges so much it fully discharges and inverts polarity. Discharging is negative current.